# How to show only one single cumulative progress bar for dropzone js when uploading multiple files at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, dropzone.js

I have been using Dropzone js Javascript library to upload multiple image files using Ajax.
The issue is that when I select multiple files to upload, it creates 1 progress bar for each file.

While I want to show only 1 single progress bar for all the selected files and make it progress according to number of files uploaded/left to server.

How can I achieve this?

I read about its documentation and other stackoverflow questions but could't find anything.

My HTML code template for dropzone preview is below:

```
<div class="table table-striped" class="files" id="previews">

  <div id="template" class="file-row">
    <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
    <div>
        <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
        <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary start">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
          <span>Start</span>
      </button>
      <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
          <span>Cancel</span>
      </button>
      <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        <span>Delete</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```